# Need help related to shiro annotation

Tags: grails

I used shiro annotations for example: @RequiresPermissions("module:books:list"). It is working fine with the permitted page.But if I try to access not permitted page it gives AuthorizationException. Can anyone tell me how to redirect to unauthorized page if AuthorizationException is caused?

Error 500: Internal Server Error
URI
/BookForAsia/authors/create
Class
org.apache.shiro.authz.AuthorizationException
Message
Not authorized to invoke method: public java.lang.Object org.ng.bookforasia.AuthorsController.create()

Answer (score 0):

As I know there are two ways to achieve that.
1.define unauthorizedUrl in your shiro-Context.xml like this

```
<bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">  
<property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager" />  
<property name="loginUrl" value="/views/login.html" />  
<property name="successUrl" value="/views/main.html" />  
<property name="unauthorizedUrl" value="/views/unauthorized.html" />  
</bean>
```

2.define error-page in your web.xml

```
<error-page>  
   <exception-type>org.apache.shiro.authz.UnauthorizedException</exception-type>  
   <location>/views/unauthorized.html</location>  
</error-page>
```

Comment: there is no shiro-context.xml
second method did not work

Comment: shiro-context.xml is the configuration of your shiro,you can also define them in your spring config xml